# Guarantees in PyQt Signals and comparistion to use a Queue

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-signals

I am considering two mechanisms to deliver results between different threads of an application. On possibility is creating a Python or PyQt queue that is filled by one thread and consumed by the thread. But I could also use PyQt Signal/Slots for the same purpose. The advantage of the later is that I can have more than one consumer without any extra work, but I was wondering if there is a downside. In particular,

1. are signals guaranteed to be relayed to the connected slot or they can be missed?
2. are signals guaranteed to be received in the same order they were emited?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. are signals guaranteed to be relayed to the connected slot or they can be missed?**

Qt guarantees that the slot receives the information. In the background in Qt the signals are in a queue that is handled by the eventloop, and this is an advantage since the queue has access to the connections.

**2. are signals guaranteed to be received in the same order they were emitted?**

As signals in my previous answer Qt saves the information that is going to be transmitted in a queue. You also have to know that slots are invoked only when the synchronous task ends or there is a sleep in some secondary thread. Then to check that the order is respected we can use the following example where 5 signal emissions are emitted, and the slot is called in the sleep.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class FooObject(QtCore.QObject):
    foosignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        counter = 0
        for _ in range(10):
            for i in range(5):
                self.foosignal.emit(counter)
                counter += 1
            QtCore.QThread.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    foo = FooObject()
    thread = QtCore.QThread()
    thread.start()
    foo.moveToThread(thread)
    foo.foosignal.connect(print)
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, foo.run)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```